# how to pass a dynamic generated QPushButton to a SIGNAL handler function in python?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to make some new `QPushButton` from list of rows and then connect them to an `Event Handler Function` using `connect` but no matter what i do, i can't connect them separately to the function.
the code is like this

```
def addItemButtons(self,chosen):

    # ----------- DELETE OLD BUTTONS ------------
    for i in reversed(range(self.layoutbottom.count())):
        self.layoutbottom.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)

    # ----------- MAKE A NEW BUTTON FOR EACH CHOSEN ENTRY -----------
    for d in chosen:
        itembtn = QPushButton("ID : "+str(d['id']))
        itembtn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.handlerFunction(str(d['id'])))
        self.layoutbottom.addWidget(itembtn)

def handlerFunction(self,txt):
    print(txt)
```

when I click on new buttons the `handlerFucntion` just prints the last button `id`!

I searched and used different methods for connecting buttons to handlerFunction but all were the same.

what is it that I am doing wrong? :/

Comment: it can be common problem with `lambda` in `for` loop. `lambda` is "lazy" - it doesn't get value from `d` when you define `lambda` function but when you execute this function - when you click button. But when you click button then `d` is set on last element from list - so every button use the same `d` - last `d`. Common solution: `lambda x=d['id']: self.handlerFunction(str(x))`. It copy value from `d['id']` to `x` and every `lambda` use own `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the value of `d['id']` wasn't being evaluated until after the loop had completed, so while all the buttons were being connected, only the last `id` was being sent.  You need to ensure that the `id` value is evaluated during the loop.

You can use `functools.partial` to do this

```
from functools import partial

for d in chosen:
    itembtn = QPushButton("ID : "+str(d['id']))
    itembtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.handlerFunction, str(d['id'])))
    self.layoutbottom.addWidget(itembtn)
```

Answer (score 1):

well! i solved it but i don't know exactly how!
this is what i did to solve the problem:

```
     for d in chosen:
        itembtn = QPushButton("ID : "+str(d['id']))
        self.connect(itembtn,SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.handleFunction)
        self.layoutbottom.addWidget(itembtn)
```

and then i changed the `handlerFunction` to this:

```
    def handleDriverSelection(self):
        print (self.sender().text()
```

i did the same thing before but with the diffrence of connecting buttons after making all of them and it was now working! maybe i did something wrong there. anyway. this is working for me. :)

Comment: You didn't need to change the connect to use the old-style syntax.  You could switch that part back, since the old-style syntax is generally discouraged.